# Projection onto Real Spherical Harmonics extended to 3D

Tags: numerical-methods, spherical-harmonics

I have a three dimensional real function that I am attempting to represent as a sum of real spherical harmonics ($Y_{l,m}$ instead of $Y_l^m$) multiplied by the distance from origin raised to some power. Essentially, I am trying to write 
$$f(r,\theta,\phi) = \sum_l \sum_m f_{l,m} \times r^lY_{l,m}(\theta,\phi)$$
 where 
$$f_{l,m} = \int_\Omega d\Omega ~ f'(\theta,\phi) Y_{l,m}(\theta,\phi)$$
 with $f'(\theta,\phi) = f(R,\theta,\phi)\frac{1}{C}$ and $C$ is a scalar that I'm choosing (i.e. I evaluate $f$ at some constant radius $R$ and scale it by some factor to account for the radius actually being nonunity).

A test that I'm trying to running is fitting $f = z^2$ to this form. I get agreement on the sphere of radius that I evaluate this function on, however off of that sphere I am getting a really poor fit in 3D (e.g. a DC value shows up).

In retrospect, this is sensible to me, since the Spherical Harmonics only form a basis for the unit sphere. Additionally, since $z^2$ (and the functions I actually will want to fit to this form) doesn't scale uniformly under varying the radius, the coefficients will depend heavily on the radius that I evaluate $f$ at. Finally perhaps the most obvious reason against this approach just by inspection is that you can't construct strictly $z^2/r^2$ out of the spherical harmonics.

My question is twofold: first, is my intuition at why this is a poor idea/not working correct? And second, is there a nice way to salvage the general idea of what I'm going for? I really would like to have terms of the form $x^iy^jz^k$ to project onto for the work that follows this step. The alternative is to just take $x^iy^jz^k$ or the spherical harmonics and do a LLS fit to the data, but I would like to avoid that if possible

Comment: See the book on harmonic analysis by Stein and Weiss, in the chapter on spherical harmonics. They decompose the space $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ into subspaces corresponding to spherical harmonics, which looks much like what you are trying to do here.

Comment: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-642-25983-8 https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4614-6660-4 Those are more modern references, especially the second is very likely to contain the answer. Sorry I cannot be more precise, I have skimmed this material but I cannot say that I have truly understood it.

Comment: Excellent, I will look these up for personal enrichment. Unfortunately this seems more involved than I have time to pursue for this specific work. Thanks